# How can i split this array with semicolons into more arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, split

I want to split this ino more semicolon arrays and the comma  splits in to a new value that I want it to be a sub-array:

```
$computers = array("computer;DT-11;12;568,36", "Samsung; RS-6000; 232; 345;456")
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i tried   command explode() but it seems explode only splits strings

Comment: `foreach` or `array_map`

Comment: @NilJay You should provide your desired result in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_push](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp)

```
/* Original Array */
$computers = array("computer;DT-11;12;568,36", "Samsung; RS-6000; 232; 345;456");

/* New Array */
$new_array = array();

/* Splits each item in the array by semi colon and pushes the result to the new array */
foreach($item in $computers){
    $new_item = explode(';', $item);
    foreach($row in $new_item){
        array_push($new_array, $row);
    }
}
```